# What is the best way to allow website users to edit already existing database records?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am building a web application that will essentially allow authenticated users access to mass amounts of data, but I don't want users to only have read-only access. If there are records missing fields but a user has found information to fill these fields or correct already populated data, I would like the user to be able to do so.

However, I'm worried about mean-spirited folks coming in and simply clearing out records out of sheer boredom and am wondering what the best way to prevent this from happening would be.

My first thought is to have users submit edits, and have a page devoted to batch approvals of these edits after myself or trusted individuals skim over the page. Of course, this would be time consuming (especially as the database grows larger), and I'm curious to know of any better ways to give users editing privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are in Rails, there are a number of plugins that provide auditing and versioning of records -

- http://github.com/andersondias/acts_as_auditable
- http://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions

These should let you build something that allows edits but still support reversions in the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Support rollbacks, like [Wikis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_software), to undo malicious edits.